# Copy User Profiles Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security

I have a corrupted User Profile on my windows 7 machine and want to associate all the libraries and other user specific information to a new account but cannot fine a way.  How do you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to help you without knowing what is corrupt / what the problems are as you may be copying over corrupt files/settings.

If you post the actual problems you are facing with the account, it is possible someone may be able to help you fix the original problem rather than just a workaround.

That aside, If this was me, I would create a new user as normal, which should also copy all the default paths and files from the default user. Then I would simply overwrite them with the files I need/want which should be located in the `AppData` folder of the original users profile.

You can find this at (if not changed):

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData
```

e.g. my user name is `wil` so the location would be:

```
C:\Users\wil\AppData
```